# combining hyperlinks with razor?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, html-helper

I tried to show dynamic urls stored in my database, but the database only have part of the URL, and I tried something like this, but it's not working, any ideas?

```
@foreach(var item in Model.dominios)
{ 
<a href="http://www.@Html.DisplayFor(model=> item.subdom).sss.com">url</a>
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You don,t need `Html.DisplayFor()` here. Build your url and put it into the link:

```
@foreach(var item in Model.dominios)
{ 
    var linkUrl = string.Format("http://www.{0}.sss.com", item.subdom);
    <a href="@linkUrl">link text</a>
}
```